# Python flask form Why HTML only show 2 decimal places?

Tags: python, html, flask

'''

```
python
forms.py
class CurrencyRateUpdateForm(FlaskForm):
    currency_rate  = DecimalField('Currency Rate', render_kw={'type':'number',  'step':'0.00001'}) 

routes.py
def currencyrate_update(currencyrate_id): 
    form = CurrencyRateUpdateForm()
    form.currency_rate.data = 1.23456
    return render_template('currencyrate_update.html', form=form)

at currencyrate_update.html, 
{{ form.currency_rate(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
```

'''

how to show all value 1.23456 rather than 1.23

Thanks.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think a `DecimalField` is? Did you try [reading the documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/), which you can find [with a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+flask+DecimalField)?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, problem solved.